# Angularjs including partials based on location

Tags: angularjs, location, partials

I want to include different headers in my index.html, one for when the user is logged in, and one for when he's not. This is my idea:

```
<script>console.log(location.hash === '#/')</script>
<div ng-if="location.hash === '#/' " id="header" ng-include="'partials/homeHeader.html'"></div>
```

The console prints true, but the part in ng-if doesn't work well. How can I solve this, or is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `location` is most likely not on the `scope` which is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your controller, create a scope item based on the location hash:

`$scope.currentHash = location.hash;`

And then use the scope item in your view:

`<div ng-if="currentHash === '#/'" ... >`